# Evento Click de botão, adicionado dinamicamente, não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou trabalhando em uma página que carrega uma lista de itens em uma `GridView`. O conteúdo está sendo carregado normalmente, mas surgiu a necessidade de adicionar uma `cell` com um texto e dois botões. Com o código abaixo está adicionando os elementos, porém o evento `click` do botão não está funcionando.

```
    protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;

                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                var btnEdit = new LinkButton
                {
                    Text = "Edit",
                };

                btnEdit.Click += btnEdit_Click;

                var btnRemove = new Button
                {
                    Text = "Remove",
                    ID = e.Row.Cells[1].Text

                };


                btnRemove.Click += btnRemove_Click;

                var chave = new Label
                {
                    Text = e.Row.Cells[1].Text
                };

                e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(chave);
                e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(btnRemove);
                e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(btnXml);

            }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```